# Absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ does not imply bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Given a function that is absolutely continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ (not some closed and bounded interval such as $[a,b]$ for a<b) is not necessarily of bounded variation on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Is there an example of a function for which this is true? I am trying to look for one but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Isn't $f(x)=x$ an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity function $f(x)=x$: it's of bounded variation on any bounded set but not on all of $\mathbb{R}$

Or if you want it to be the integral of its derivative on every $[-\infty, a]$, $f(x)=\exp(x)/(1+\exp(x))$